# How to reset input to DialogFramgment after initial build?

Tags: android, dialogfragment

*EDIT: Attached the code for my onCickListener which sends Rating Value to and then Show my Dialog.*
I have a TextView which shows me a rating in numbers format (4.5). And when I press this TextView a dialog pops up to let me change the rating trough a RatingBar. The Ratingbar`s rating is set to equal the TextView Rating when it pops up. This functions as expected and the TextView is updated to the new rating when I press OK. BUT when I press the TextView again, the initial first value is shown and not the value which I just updated it to. I have figured out as much as this is because I have all my code within the onCreateDialog (). I have tried to get this to work by using OnStart() and onResume() but then my app crashes. How do I write this code correctly?

Attached is my functional code with all code set within the onCreadeDialog()

```
public class RatingDialog extends DialogFragment{

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

    // Get the layout inflater
    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();

    // Inflate and set the layout for the dialog
    // Pass null as the parent view because its going in the dialog layout
    final View DialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_rating, null);

    /**
     * Retrieve the argument "num" (Previously rating) and set ratingbar´s rating equal to this.
     */
    getArguments().getFloat("num");
    RatingBar ValueView = (RatingBar) DialogView.findViewById(R.id.Ratingbar);
    ValueView.setRating(getArguments().getFloat("num"));
    builder.setView(DialogView)

            // Add action buttons
            .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    /**
                     * Get the new value from the Ratingbar and send this back to the AddRating TextView
                     */
                    RatingBar ValueView = (RatingBar) DialogView.findViewById(R.id.Ratingbar);
                    float Value = ValueView.getRating();
                    TextView Text = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.AddRating);
                    Text.setText(String.valueOf(Value));
                    RatingDialog.this.getDialog().cancel();
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    RatingDialog.this.getDialog().cancel();
                }
            });

    return builder.create();
}
```

}

Below is the code for onCickListener which sends Rating Value to and then Show my Dialog:

```
/**
     * Set the On Click Listener and send the Rating value to the Dialog 
     */
    final TextView Rating = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.AddRating);
    String S = (String) Rating.getText();
    final Float F;

    if (S==""){
        F=0.0f;}
    else
        F = Float.valueOf(S);

    Rating.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            RatingDialog newFragment = new RatingDialog();
            newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "Rating");

            /**
             * Send Verdien av rating til dialogvinduet
             */
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putFloat("num", F);
            newFragment.setArguments(args);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Post the code where you show the DialogFragment(more precisely, the code where you set/calculate the value that you pass as arguments to the DialogFragment).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing same `F` value all the time.
It should be:

```
    final TextView rating = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.AddRating);

    rating.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            RatingDialog newFragment = new RatingDialog();
            newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "Rating");

            /**
             * Send Verdien av rating til dialogvinduet
             */
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putFloat("num", TextUtils.isEmpty(rating.getText()) ?
                    0.0f : Float.valueOf(rating.getText().toString()));
            newFragment.setArguments(args);
        }
    });
```

In that case you will pass actual value of `rating` TextView.

And yes, please follow [java code convention](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-150003.pdf). Because it's hard to read your code.